# Adjust NSWindow height from bottom?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frame, nswindow

Suppose I have a window named `mWindow`.  To increase the height I would do this to the frame:

```
NSRect windowFrame = [mWindow frame]; 
windowFrame.size.height += 100.0f;
[mWindow setFrame:windowFrame];
```

However, this increase the height of the *top* of the window, not the bottom.  How can I make it add more window at the bottom instead of the top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the way coordinates work in Cocoa, you'll have to do some extra steps to make this work:

```
NSRect windowFrame = [mWindow frame];
windowFrame.size.height += 100;
windowFrame.origin.y -= 100;
[mWindow setFrame:windowFrame display:YES];
```

Alternatively, you can use the `setFrameOrigin:` or `setFrameTopLeftPoint:` methods of NSWindow.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can always adjust the origin accordingly, i.e. make it higher *and* move it downwards.

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet. You have to adjust `origin.y` according to `offset`

```
func change(height: CGFloat) {
  var frame = window.frame
  let offset = height - frame.size.height
  frame.size.height += offset
  frame.origin.y -= offset

  window.setFrame(rect, display: true)
}
```